# moment fromNow returns in 5 hours when parsing utc

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

trying to format utc time from server in time ago using moment.js fromNow but in some occasions I get "in 5 hours" instead.

timestamp from a server - 2017-11-29T15:03:21

```
var utcTime = new Date(timestamp);
var timeAgo = moment(utcTime).fromNow();    
console.log(timeAgo)
```

all dates are in past so how can I fix this so I dont get time in a few hours ?

Comment: Well what do you want? `fromNow` is returning exactly what the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) states it should return. I am not sure what the confusion is. Maybe you are looking for [difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)?

Comment: I want to get a few seconds ago, few minutes ago...while I get in 5 hours which is in future. so I was wondering how to format it for timezones

Comment: Note that "2017-11-29T15:03:21" will be parsed as local, so if the client timezone has a different offset to the server, it will represent a different moment in time. If you want it treated as UTC, append a "Z" to the timestamp: "2017-11-29T15:03:21Z". You might also do `moment(timestamp + 'Z').fromNow()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want "2017-11-29T15:03:21" treated as UTC, you can either use moment's *utc* method or just append a "Z" to the string. Since you're already using moment.js, it's more reliable to parse it with moment.js than the built-in parser:

```js
var timestamp = "2017-11-30T00:20:48";

// Append Z
console.log(moment(timestamp + 'Z').fromNow());

// Use .utc
console.log(moment.utc(timestamp).fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell moment that this date is in UTC using [moment.utc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

```
var utcTime = new Date(timestamp);
var timeAgo = moment.utc(utcTime).fromNow();
```

If you don't, moment assumes this date is in your local timezone (which I can tell is Eastern Standard Time by the offset).

In your local timezone, this date is actually 5 hours in the future. Only in UTC is it a few seconds ago, because your local timezone is 5 hours behind UTC.

Answer (score 2):

As per documents https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

you can customize the locale https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/

As  default locale `future time` will be  `future: "in %s",` having `in` which is as per documents. if you want to change it then update the locale and use as you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: all dates are in past but I am getting in for future time due to utc I assume

Comment: yes it depends on which side of timezone you are and you could be behind UTC time and it will be a future time.

Comment: I understand this so how to address it ?

Comment: so to address is always make sure both the time which you are comparing is in same timezone..either convert the local time to UTC or other time to local to ensure it provides proper output